# How to pass parameters between vba and vb

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I'm making a tool, where I need to start a programm (which I want to code with VB) by using VBA in an Excle file. When I close that programm, it should give back a parameter to the VBA script.

I started just now with the VBA script and didn't code anything of the VB programm yet. But I need to know, what to write in the VBA script and wheter this is possible.

So it should work like this:

- I'm in the Excel file and I press a button
- The programm is starting (also getting a parameter from the Excel file, this is not that important yet)
- In that programm I configurate some stuff
- Closing that Programm it should give back a ID of that configuration
- I'm getting back to the Excel file with this ID

Is this possible? And what do I need to write in the VBA script and in the Programm to give back a parameter?

I hope you understand what I mean and you can help me

Comment: You could read [StdOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbxxzwb5(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Have you considered writing your VB.Net code as a COM Object library?  This way you create an instance of your VB.Net class in the VBA code and then call a function on that instance to return the needed value.  See: [Walkthrough: Creating COM Objects with Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x66s8zcd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could set your VB .exe to return an Exit code. Just make sure the id isn't 0 (means ran successfully) or 259 (calling process will think process is still running). The VBA below runs an .exe, waits for it to close, then returns the exit code.

```
Option Explicit

' Api declarations
Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long


Public Function RunProgram(ByVal strFilename As String) As Long

    '# PURPOSE: Run a program, wait until closed, and return the exit code

    Dim TaskID As Long
    Dim hProc As Long
    Dim lExitCode As Long

    Const ACCESS_TYPE = &H400
    Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103

    ' Open the program
    TaskID = Shell(strFilename, 1)
    hProc = OpenProcess(ACCESS_TYPE, False, TaskID)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Cannot start " & strFilename, vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Function
    End If


    ' Wait until program is closed
    Do
        GetExitCodeProcess hProc, lExitCode
        DoEvents
    Loop While lExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE

    ' Return the program's exit code
    RunProgram = lExitCode

End Function
```